# Send files to a ftp server and then check if it was really sent using .bat

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I was making a `.bat` code to send `.txt` files to a specific folder on my ftp server. But I also wanted a way to check if these files were really uploaded. I searched a lot on the internet and unfortunately, I realized that it can't be done using `.bat` command.
So I tried using another way: The `.bat` will send the files and then will take it back to the folder, if the file already exists in the folder it will show a message that the file was successfully uploaded.

I did this script below, but the part of the "checking if was uploaded" is not working right.

Someone can help me?

```
@echo off
@setlocal enableextensions
@cd /d "%~dp0"
mode 34,12
color 0a

Ping www.google.nl -n 1 -w 1000 >nul 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 (set internet=Nao foi possivel se conectar ao servidor) else (set internet=Conectado) >nul 2>nul

echo  %internet%

if "%internet%"=="No connection" goto 1
if "%internet%"=="Conected" goto 2

:1 
echo  No connection
echo.
echo  Try later...
echo.
pause
exit

:2
( echo open ftp.xxxxxxxxxxx.com
echo xxxxxxx
echo xxxxxxx
echo ascii
echo lcd "c:\Vendas Pay&Go\files"
echo cd "Vendas Cartões Pay&Go"
echo cd "ECO"

echo mput *.txt 
echo bye 
)> %temp%\ftpsend.dat
ftp -i -s:%temp%/ftpsend.dat >nul 2>nul
del /f /s /q %temp%\ftpsend.dat >nul 2>nul

( echo open ftp.xxxxxxx.com
echo xxxxxxx
echo xxxxxxx
echo ascii
echo lcd "c:\Vendas Pay&Go\files"
echo cd "Vendas Cartões Pay&Go"
echo cd "ECO"

echo mget *.txt 
echo bye 
)> %temp%\ftpsend.dat
ftp -i -s:%temp%/ftpsend2.dat >nul 2>nul
del /f /s /q %temp%\ftpsend2.dat >nul 2>nul

if %*.txt% exist goto3

:4
echo File was not uploaded
pause

:3
echo File Uploaded.
del /s /f /q "c:\Vendas Pay&Go\files\*.txt"
```

Comment: If you capture the verbose output of the FTP command it will tell you if the file was successfully uploaded.  There is no need to try and download it again to see if it successfully uploaded.  I have never seen any log file tell me a file was successfully uploaded and not see the file on the ftp server.  I run dozens of automated FTP batches files every day and parsing the verbose output has never been a problem.

Comment: Regardless of the previous comment, if you actually read the help file for the `IF` command you would see this usage syntax: `IF EXIST filename command`.  So based on that information what are you doing wrong?

Comment: @Squashman I guess there's some errors in the script. Anyway, i'm checking it. I liked what you said about the verbose output of the ftp, but i just wanted it shows in a separetted echo, not together with all ftp echos.

Comment: `ftp -i -s:%temp%/ftpsend.dat | find /I "file successfully transferred"`

Comment: @Squashman Good! I tried using condittionals `if` using the word `file sucessufully transferred` as reference to make a `echo` action. But nothing happened, maybe i guess because it's a internal code showing. I wanted it show if uploaded sucessufully: `File transfered` or if not uploaded `No transfered. Try again later`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to conditional execution to display a message you can do something like this.  The && means the previous command was successful.  The || means the previous command was not successful.

```
(ftp -i -s:%temp%/ftpsend.dat | find /I "file successfully transferred" >nul) && (echo File Successfully Transferred) || ( echo File not transferred. Tray again later.)
```

Updated version based on comment below

```
(ftp -i -s:%temp%/ftpsend.dat | find /I "file successfully transferred" >nul) && (
        echo File successfully sent.
        del /f /s /q "c:\Vendas Pay&Go\files\*.txt" >nul
    ) || (
        cls
        echo File not uploaded. Try later.
    )
```

Comment: Just improvised your answer `(ftp -i -s:%temp%/ftpsend.dat | find /I "file successfully transferred" >nul) && (echo File successfully sent.) && (del /f /s /q "c:\Vendas Pay&Go\files\*.txt" >nul) || (cls) && ( echo File not uploaded. Try later.) `

Comment: Good! Thank you.